# Button on accordion (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating several accordions headers and bodies from a vuejs data object.

The header is a button that triggers the body content and contains several datas and 2 nested buttons.

1st one to delete current header and its body from the DOM
2nd one to edit the body.

Second button is supposed to open a modal but for some reason when i click on this modal button, it triggers the accordion's collapse and modal at the same time creating a visual bug.

**How can I trigger a nested button without triggering the main button?**

Comment: Please provide your code in order to be able to correct it. You can use "Code Snippet" that has an option for VueJs code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see your code to tell your for sure, but it sounds like you can just use a different on click event for the second button?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sadly i find it difficult to provide more details as i dont know the exact markup of the dropdown and the code powering it.